# Install PostgreSQL under a system user other than “postgres”?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-12.04

I need to run my current `Postgresql 9.3` under a system user other than `postgres`, say admin OR I need to install `Postgresql 9.3` with the default user as say `admin` on `Ubuntu 12.04`

Comment: Why do you need to have user other than `postgres`?

Comment: to maintain a policy

Comment: Normally you would just need to create a new user, ensure that the new user can write to the postgres data directories and create a startup script to start postgres as that user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An installed PostgreSQL on Debian/Ubuntu is essentially:

- a set of binaries per version that any user can potentially run to spawn and manage a new instance.
- a datadir per instance that only its owner can use.

If the initial situation consists of `9.3` binaries being installed through Ubuntu packages, a non-postgres Unix user can spawn an instance by doing:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/initdb --pgdata=$HOME/pginstance [other-options]
```

Then start this instance with:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_ctl -D $HOME/pginstance start
```

and stop it with:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_ctl -D $HOME/pginstance stop
```

Obviously `$HOME/pginstance` can be wherever the user has the permission to write.

This instance would be unrelated to the `postgres` user and the scripts that come with the Ubuntu packages wouldn't know or care about it. It's entirely managed by the user who started it. It may coexist with others, but each instance must have its own port (defined in `postgresql.conf` inside the data directory).

Comment: Thanks Daniel. It worked and this was what I was looking for.